# How to sum time interval stored as string in MySQL like 5 days 10:20:00

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select

I need to write a select query to sum the time interval from MySQL table where the time interval is stored as text and in the format similar to following

```
10 days 3:28:31
```

In the PostgreSQL query we can simply use `::interval` and it converts above to interval and we can use Sum method over it in PostgreSQL query but I am unable to do the same in MySQL. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have an `interval` data type.  It does use the `interval` keyword -- which is a bit confusing.  But that is a syntactic element, rather than a data type.

One thing you *can* do is use the `time` data type.  This supports times up to 838 hours -- or about 35 days.  That is enough for many purposes.

Otherwise, the recommendation is to use a single time unit and to store the value as a numeric quantity.  For instance, "5 days 10:20:00" would be:

- 5.43055555556 days (5 + 10 / 24 + 20 / (24*60))
- 130.333333333 hours
- 7820 minutes